# Using client.DownloadFile();

Tags: c#

I'm using client.DownloadFile(); for my console project..
now my question is:
if my command goes like this:

```
client.DownloadFile(http://url.com/random-name, "filename")
```

what i need is instead of downloading the file and save it as "filename" i want the filename to be "what ever the random file name is" is that possible?

Comment: i just edited my question, the problem is the file is a random file and is always changing to other file names

Answer (score 2):

Get the filename using [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx). You can get the `AbsoluteUri` property of your URI, or just pass the full URI yourself like you've done in your post.

```
string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(myUri.AbsoluteUri); 
client.DownloadFile(myUri, filename);
```

Comment: i just edited my question, the problem is the file is a random file and is always changing to other file names –

Comment: @BxcbSbdsb Just put your new path as the parameter for `GetFileName`.